# Is the usage of 'alongside' right in, 'I will be studying alongside working.'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is there another way of saying this? Is, 'I will be studying and working at the same time' a better way of saying it?

Comment: Do you mean literally at the same time - as in reading a textbook while you're not busy helping customers?  Or do you mean that part of your week will be spent in school and part of your week will be spent at a job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a great usage of *alongside*; though it's comprehensible by native speakers, they'll likely peg you as a non-native speaker for that alone.

The way it's normally used is with a noun, not a verb.

> I will be studying alongside other students.

Possibly you are confusing the progressive verb *working* with the gerund form of *working* ("Working in a coal mine is dangerous") which functions as a noun.

What you probably want to say is

> I will be studying **along with** working.

There are multiple ways to link two verbs together. This is one, but still probably not the best one. Better might be

> I will be studying **together with** working.

In my view, the latter sufficiently compartmentalizes the two disciplines, while at the same time linking them contemporaneously.

Answer (score 0):

operating or working in tandem

Comment: @what is tandem,can I have further explianation?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).